How do you find the angle and distance when you maximize the area of an annular sector bound within a circle?
Point A is a distance (D) away from point B. Point B is the center of a circle of a certain radius (R) that is less than distance D. Two segments (J and K) are symmetrical across a line containing point A and point B. The segments have one endpoint at point A and the other endpoint on the perimeter of the circle (J2 and K2), but the segment should also intersect the perimeter of the circle (J1 and K1). J1 and K1, as well as J2 and K2, should be connected by an arc (arc 1 and arc 2) of a distance relative to point A.
A four-sided shape (an annular sector) should form within the circle; two sides being arc 1 and arc 2, and the other two sides being a straight segment between J1 and J2 then K1 and K2. Here is a diagram: https://imgur.com/a/V5Wp6Qv
When you maximize the area of that shape, given D and R, what is the following:
the distance from Point A to arc 1
the distance from Point A to arc 2
the angle formed at point A between J and K
I only really know some trigonometry so I don't really know how I'd approach this. I do know that we can calculate the area by finding the difference between the distance from point A to arc 1 to arc 2, then multiplying it by the angle formed divided by two. I just don't know how to come up with a formula (preferably something I can put into excel) that would maximize that area.
I do realize that it likely involves finding the two triangles that can be formed when having an angle (theta divided by two), and two sides not conjoined at that angle - D and R.

It would be really nice if a diagram can be provided

This is the best I could do: https://imgur.com/a/V5Wp6Qv

Do we know values of $AJ_1,AJ_2$ etc

No, that's part of what we're trying to solve for.

Oh alright, I thought by distance you meant the perpendicular distance from A to the arc 1

Aren't they the same?

Regardless, the only thing we know the values of is D and R.

Outline of a solution.
Pick your coordinate system so that $A=(0,0)$  and the  given circle is centered at $(D,0)$.   The equation of that circle is therefore.
(1) $(x-D)^2 + y^2 =R^2$.
The equation of any line through $A$ has the form
(2) $y=mx$ where $m=\tan \alpha$ in which $\alpha $ is the angle that the line makes with the $x$ axes.
The area of the upper half of your figure is
(3) $ f(\alpha) =\alpha (R_2^2- R_1^2)/2$  where $R_2$ and $R_1$ are the  distances from the origin to the two points where the tilted line cuts the given circle.
The circle equation (1) can also be expanded as
(4) $ x^2 + y^2 = 2xD -D^2+R^2$.(Note that the left side is the square of the distance from the origin to a point on the circle. This is useful later.)
To solve for the locations of those intersection points first replace $y=mx$ into  (1) to deduce that
(5) $(x-D)^2 + m^2 x^2 -R^2=0$.
This is a quadratic equation for $x$ of the form $ax^2 + bx + c=0$ where  $a= 1+ m^2$ is the only coefficient that depends on $m$. The two  roots  can be written down explicitly via the usual quadratic formula: $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{ b^2- 4ac}}{2a}$.
Denote the solutions of the quadratic by  $x_1, x_2$. (It is too  tedious to typeset their complete description in detail;  but it is clear how they depend on $m$ and thus are explicit functions of $\alpha$.)
Now make  use of (4)  two times, for $x= x_1$ and $x= x_2$, and subtract the two equations. Thus we can write $R_2^2- R_1^2 = 2(x_2-x_1)D$. The latter is a difference of two explicit functions of $\alpha$. In fact it has the form $2D(\frac{ \sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{a}$.
Thus $f(\alpha)$ can be written down completely. By plotting its graph you should be able to estimate its maximum.
